# Doubt about Lemma 4.1 in Endpoint Strichartz Estimates by Keel-Tao

Tags: partial-differential-equations, strichartz-estimates

In Lemma 4.1 "Endpoint Strichartz Estimates" by Keel-Tao the inequality
$$ \int_{1 \leq s-t \leq 2} \langle U^*(s)F(s), U^*(t)G(t) \rangle ds dt =:T_0(F,G) \lesssim \lVert F \rVert_{2,a'} \lVert G \rVert_{2,b'}$$ is proved for $F,G$ supported in a time interval of duration $1$. Then, by using the fact that $T_0$ is localized in time, the result is extended to any $F,G$.

I don't understand what it means for $T_0$ to be localized in time, since the integration region is unbounded.

Comment: For fixed $s$, the bounds on the $t$ integration are finite. Perhaps this is what is meant?